# Inertia Manual Share State Lazily Inside Controller not Working

Tags: javascript, laravel, controller, inertiajs

I'm going crazy because of this one, I have this address form in a very nested component and a route to validate the form input data. In the controller, I want to return back to the same page but share the form data to be able to fetch it in a parent component. I'm trying to follow Inertia DOCs to lazily share the data to be available to all components but for some reason this isn't working!

1- I'm submitting the form:

```js
const submitAddressCheck = () => {
    shippingDetailsForm.post(
        route("cart.checkaddress", [props.webshop_slug]),
        {}
    );
};
```

2- The form gets validated as expected but it doesn't share the data globally to all components.
CartController.php

```php
    public function checkaddress(StoreAddressCheckRequest $request)
    {
        Inertia::share(
            'testing',
            fn ($request) => $request
                ? $request
                : null
        );

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Once I submit the form it gets validated and that's it, no new props passed, the data isn't being shared to my parent component or anything. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Inertia::share()` will not persist any data passed between requests. So if you share data and then redirect to another route, then your shared data will not be passed.

You are probably looking for [Flash messages](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#flash-messages). With flash messages you use the `with()` method when redirecting to show errors, success messages, anything you like. Make sure you follow the documentation and add the code to the `HandleInertiaRequests` middleware.

When it is time to redirect, you do something like this:

```php
return redirect()->back()->with('testing', $request->all());
```

Comment: Can I pass form data as a flash message? I think not. All I need is to return back with the data saved in props if that's possible.

Comment: You can pass whatever you want back. A better way to do it is to make sure that the response in the controller you are returning to contain the data you want. For example: `Controller 1 (Contains Models 1-5) -> Create & Save new model -> Return back to Controller 1 (Now contains Models 1-6)`.